# How can I pass parameters from a SQL query to a vb.net function?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, ms-access

I am attempting to transition/retire some solutions I have written in VBA/MS Access over to VB.net/SQL server and am very much new at the vb.net/SQL part.  In MS Access I have a number of action and select queries that pass field values as parameters over to a VBA function and return a value to the query.  I am looking for information on how to accomplish this in a VB.net/SQL server scenario. Is it possible to call a SQL query from vb that uses data from the SQL query/table back in the VB function?

So far I am able to send a SQL command from VB.net using a basic calculation in a vb.net function, but I am uncertain on how to use some of the fields in the query/table as parameters for the calculations in the vb function.

In Access I would use this query to pass the parameters to the get_pricefunction function:

```
SELECT get_pricefunction([cost],[status],[itemcode],"ACMEstore") AS price
FROM tbl_items;
```

---

```
Public get_pricefunction(_cost, _status, _itemcode, _store )
            Return <some calculation>
    End Function
```

So far what I have in VB to update a table with a price.  This code works to set all the fields ss_price to the same thing.  I am hoping to have update the prices to the calculation in the function, but the function relies on information in the table:

```
'CODE FOR CONNECTING TO THE DATABASE....
Dim q As String = "update ss_scrap_blemprice SET ss_price =" & getpricefunction()
Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(q, _connection)
           cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

---

```
Public get_pricefunction()
        Return <some calculation using info from the table>
End Function
```

Is there an equivalent with vb.net/SQL server to pass field values to the vb function?

Thanks in advance, and happy to clarify if needed.

Comment: You have two choices. Firstly, your VB code can execute a query to get data back and then use it in its own calculations, possibly passing the result into another query. The alternative is to write functions in .NET and then install them into SQL Server, in which case you can then call them as stored procedures in SQL code. I've never done the latter myself so I can't provide details but, if you're interested in that, search the web and/or MSDN for "SQL CLR".

Comment: check if this link could help at all. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/linq/how-to-use-table-valued-user-defined-functions